# WinForms Databinding

Tags: winforms, data-binding

I've built some business objects, and I've built a "data access layer" that will read, update, delete, etc.   Now I want to bind these objects to grids/text boxes/combo's etc in a WinForm's app.

I could do the manual method like:

```
txtName.Text = employee.Name;
```

and then on save do something like

```
employee.Name = txtName.Text;
```

But I'd much rather use the "RAD" features of VS 2008.  I've done some googling but I'm not finding any quick tutorial that shows me what I need to do to my business objects to allow them to be "data bound".  Can anyone help?

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial on WinForms data binding: [Data Binding in .NET / C# Windows Forms](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html)

Comment: I am releasing a set of video tutorials showing how to perform data bindings using Winforms. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9f7IoKQIraQ&list=PL8vZpHuqa_hMeMEmEU8eS3nJnZRZy5SbD