# display items in a windows form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

What would be the best way to display items in c# in a form

For example I have a pizza(small,medium,large) button.

If I press the small pizza button it will display like this:

```
Order:
Item          Quantity    Price
Small Pizza   1           3.99
```

If I press the add pepperoni button it will display like this:

```
Order:
Item          Quantity    Price
Small Pizza   1           3.99
-Pepperoni    1           0.99
```

If I press the add pepperoni button it will display like this(making it double pep):

```
Order:
Item          Quantity    Price
Small Pizza   1           3.99
-Pepperoni    2           1.98
```

Also adding another item such as a large pizza it will display like this:

```
Order:
Item          Quantity    Price
Small Pizza   1           3.99
-Pepperoni    2           1.98
Large Pizza   1           6.99
```

I basically just want it so you can see what you've added to the order.

What would be the best way to do this with c# and windows form?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it accordingly.

Comment: It's not homework. I'm trying to learn c# and windows form since I've been doing c++ and It's easy to display in a command window.

Comment: But aren't you following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984454(v=vs.71).aspx? It tells you!

Comment: Actually that does help Steve, I'll look over it. However I still want it to display my order in the form and just be able to update it if I want to add/remove items.

Comment: @SteveCav There is no example for multi-columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a general look at some of the tools available for developing c# applications focused on winforms I'd point you to the MSDN How Tos:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb798022#winforms

There are some specific for list controls which others have mentioned, and several provide examples of how to hook up button press events to performing user interface actions.

I would also advise the use of databinding in place of "manually" setting/retrieving values.

[WinForms Databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454959/winforms-databinding)

Comment: I'll look into databinding but the how to tips really help. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like the how-to link is broken.  I perused MSDN and found an archived version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zftbwa2b(v=vs.100).aspx   However, if you are looking at this now, I'd now suggest moving forward with the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) UI framework as opposed to WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

you can use list box with multi-columns
this link will help you
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/multicolumnlistbox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer since the question is not well formed in my opinion.

If you are asking for specific GUI control, I will answer:

ListView, XPTable, ObjectListView, etc... it depends on specific requirements.

If you are asking more for best application design, the answer would be to implement MVP design pattern, or just to use data binding. It is really hard to suggest anything more specific, since question doesn't describe any specific use case.

Edit:
So for lists the XPTable control (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/XPTable.aspx - and updated version on sourceforge) should be OK. ObjectListView gives also advanced options, but as far as I know is not free. I don't recommend to use native .NET controls, since they aren't really customizable.

Comment: I just want a simple display of list like the same way you can just display in a command window. If you add/remove/update from a list it just changes that.