# Binding DTO fields to WinForm controls (e.g. TextBox)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a simple DTO class like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

On my WinForm `OnLoad` event, I generate an object of type `User` like this (for testing purpose. in real scenario, the DTO object is passed to the form constructor):

```
User myUser = new User()
{
    FirstName = "Latheesan",
    LastName = "Kanes",
    Age = 26
};
```

Now on my form, I have the following text box controls:

[image]

My textbox controls are correctly named to match the DTO fields.

My question; is it possible to bind the DTO field `myUser`.`FirstName` to the form control's textbox `FirstName` so that value from my DTO is populated on the form and changing the value on the form updates the DTO itself?

Currently, I am having to do this manually...

e.g. `OnLoad`:

```
FirstName.Text = myUser.FirstName;
```

e.g. `OnFormClosed`:

```
myUser.FirstName = FirstName.Text;
```

I'd like to automated it by binding the controls to the DTO, if at all possible...

Comment: Did you read about [Data binding with Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8aebh9k.aspx)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454959/winforms-databinding