# How to get values from multiple textboxes at once?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a form which has many textboxes on for the user to enter data. The problem is that I cant work out how to get the values from the boxes!

The user presses "save" to save all the values, so I have a procedure to "save" this information, but as said I cant work out how to extract the values. Ive had a search and found nothing that can hep. heres some code in c#:

```
// this is the procedure i want to use the value in
public static save()
{
    MessageBox.Show(trackBoxString);
}

// the event handler. trackBoxString is a public static string so that I could access it from                       different procedures
private void trackBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    trackBoxString = trackBox.Text;
}
```

this just opens a blank message box

some more code as requested

public static raceBoxString = "";
public static trackBoxString = "";

```
    static void saveSetup()
    {
        try
        {
            string server = "localhost";
            string database = "*****";
            string uid = """""""";
            string password = """"""";
            MySqlConnection connection;
            string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password;
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            connection.Close();

            MessageBox.Show(trackBoxString);

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

private void raceBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            raceBoxString = raceBox.Text;
        }

```
    private void trackBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trackBoxString = trackBox.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Alos winforms or wpf or other?

Comment: @ZoomVirus: It can be changed. It is just `static`, not `const`.

Comment: ok, tried it without static but then its not happy, wont run. What should i use instead? Its also on windows form

Comment: Why not just get trackBox.Text in your Save() method??

Comment: You should show a bit more code, because I'm not sure to understand WHY you felt the need to use a static string. @Zoom static isn't const.

Comment: when i tried that i get the error messageError                   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: What error message?  (Are you calling Save() from a different thread?)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of _[WinForms Databinding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454959/winforms-databinding)_

Comment: @Ian save() is called when the user clicks on a button, I havnt shown that code

Comment: Fine - so what's the exception?

Comment: i have a message box to show the value of trackBoxString so i could see if it works, and the message box shows up blank when i do MessageBox.Show(trackBoxString);

Comment: You should be able to get the value of trackBox.Text directly in your button click handler Save().  What's the error in this case?

Comment: same error as above, an object reference is missing

Comment: ...  You should be able to get the value of trackBox.Text directly in the method without using the static.  You said it gave an error? What is the error in this case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok, i moved the trackBox.Text into the save button event handler, there was an error. But when i saved and reopened the program it was fine, so i think windows had a bit of a moment! thanks for your help

the error was;

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

Comment: Don't mention it.   Although... mentioning the error would be very helpful for others!..

Comment: Aha yes, both of your 'save' methods are static.  I didn't notice this before.  You wouldn't be able to access the textbox value from a static method.  Why do they need to be static?  Anyway, sounds like you've solved it.